# python cluster animation using matplotlib and different colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to create an animation of my clustering where each cluster is a different color on a scatter plot and there are several clusters per plot. The next plot to show has the same clusters and colors but a different location.

I've searched around and so far have this (timePeriodData refers to a list of cluster objects. Each list contains the clusters for that time/plot and the cluster object has the x, y, and color data.):

```
plt.ion()

fig,ax = subplots(1,1)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
fig.canvas.draw()
background = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)

for timeData in timePeriodData:
    plt.clf()
    #print timeperiod
    for cluster in timeData:
        #ax.scatter(cluster.dataX,cluster.dataY, color = cluster.color)
        # restore background
        plt.scatter(cluster.dataX,cluster.dataY, color = cluster.color)
    #plt.show()
    #fig.canvas.restore_region(background)

    # redraw just the points
    #ax.draw_artist()

    # fill in the axes rectangle
    #fig.canvas.blit(ax.bbox)
    plt.draw()
    time.sleep(1)
```

But the plot window eventually hangs and doesn't continue plotting after about 5 plots. You can see in the comments I also tried to save the background and update that, but I am doing something wrong there. What exactly needs to be updated confuses me and I can't find good documentation on what needs to be passed to draw_artist.

I've also tried to use the animation feature of matplotlib, but can't seem to get it working with what I am trying to do.

```
timeperiods = 4
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#fig = plt.figure()
def update(timePeriod, *args):
    clusterNum = 0
    for cluster in args[timePeriod]:
        scat = ax.scatter(cluster.dataX,cluster.dataY, color = cluster.color)
        clusterNum +=1
    #scat = ax.scatter(dataX, dataY, c = scalarMap.to_rgba(values[clusterNum]))
    return scat

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=xrange(timeperiods),
                                  fargs=(timePeriodData), blit = True)
plt.show()
```

It says something is not iterable, but I'm sure what part it is referring to. I'm also not sure if I can continually assign scat to ax.scatter and it will add the points or not. but I assume so. Error message is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 276, in resize
    self.show()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 348, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1040, in draw
    self.canvas.draw_event(renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1693, in draw_event
    self.callbacks.process(s, event)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 527, in process
    proxy(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 405, in __call__
    return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 832, in _end_redraw
    self._post_draw(None, self._blit)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 778, in _post_draw
    self._blit_draw(self._drawn_artists, self._blit_cache)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 787, in _blit_draw
    for a in artists:
 TypeError: 'PathCollection' object is not iterable
```

Any help getting a working system would be great!

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the error message and traceback you get when you run.

Comment: Just added the error.

Comment: Have you tried setting `blit=False` in the animation call?